# I have an external file saved with username and highscore, I need them to be ordered

Tags: python, python-3.x

My external file is saved in lines as 'username,score' and I need the file to be sorted with the score in descending order, here is what I have so far:

```
def Highscores():
    with open ('leaderboards.txt','a') as scores:
        scores.write (Uusername +','+ str(score)+'\n')
        sorted(lines, key=itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
    with open ('leaderboards.txt','r') as read:
        head = [next(read) for x in xrange(5)]
        print (head)
```

I understand that there is an error in line 4, but, once it has ordered it, I need it to print the top 5 lines
e.g:

**In the text file:**

```
User,40  
User2,39  
User3,25
```

**and prints:**

```
User,40
User2,39
User3,25
```

Comment: what is your input and expected output?

Comment: My input is  Username and they play a game and get a score, then my expected output is the username,score ordered

Comment: Your code is not revelant. We can't run it on our own. But why do you write in file before sorting your data ?

Comment: The writing is done in the third line in the code

Comment: what do you mean by ordered?

Comment: Like , All usernames are assigned to a score, and the scores are put in descending order (5,4,3,2,1) and are each on separate lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy if you use `pandas`.
Assume the input.txt is like

```
User,40
User2,39
User3,25
```

than the following code will solve your problem

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input.txt',header=None,names=['username','score'])
df.sort_values(by='score',ascending=False)
df.to_csv('output.txt')
print(df.head(n=5))
```